# Money class with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, finance, overloading

I have program that uses a `Money` class which has several constructors for different methods of input and overloaded operators to add, subtract, and compare values.

I am having difficulty defining my `int asCents(const Money& amount) const;` method so that it can be used in other functions. Used correctly, is it best practice to return the integer it produces as opposed to creating two new ones equivalent to it (`amount.getCents() + amount.getDollars() * 100;`)? How else can this program be improved?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

class Money {

public:

    Money();
    Money(double asMoney);
    Money(int justDollars);
    Money(int withDollars, int withCents);

    friend const Money operator +(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2);
    friend const Money operator -(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2);

    friend const Money operator %(const Money& amount, double percentage);

    friend bool operator ==(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2);
    friend bool operator <(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2);
    friend bool operator >(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2);
    friend const Money operator -(const Money& amount1);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount);
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& inputStream, Money& amount);

    int getDollars() const { return dollars; }
    int getCents() const { return cents; }

    //int asCents(const Money& amount) const; // unused
    Money percent(const Money& amount, double percentage) const;

private:

    int dollars;
    int cents;
    int dollarsPart(double amount) const;
    int centsPart(double amount) const;
    int round(double number) const;
};

    int Money::centsPart(double amount) const {
    double doubleCents = amount * 100;
    int intCents = (round(fabs(doubleCents))) % 100;
    if (amount < 0)
        intCents = -intCents;
    return intCents;
}

int Money::dollarsPart(double amount) const { return static_cast<int>(amount); }
int Money::round(double amount) const { return static_cast<int>(floor(amount + 0.5)); }

const int asCents(const Money& amount) {
    int amountAsCents = amount.getCents() + amount.getDollars() * 100;
    return amountAsCents;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount) {
    int absDollars = abs(amount.dollars);
    int absCents = abs(amount.cents);
    if (amount.dollars < 0 || amount.cents < 0)
        outputStream << "$-";
    else
        outputStream << '$';
        outputStream << absDollars;
    if (absCents >= 10)
        outputStream << '.' << absCents;
    else
        outputStream << '.' << '0' << absCents;
    return outputStream;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& inputStream, Money& amount) {
    char dollarSign;
    while (inputStream >> dollarSign && dollarSign != '$') {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a dollar sign ($) for money input.\n" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter an amount of money: ";
    }
    double amountAsDouble;
    inputStream >> amountAsDouble;
    amount.dollars = amount.dollarsPart(amountAsDouble);
    amount.cents = amount.centsPart(amountAsDouble);
    return inputStream;
}   

const Money operator +(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    int centsSum = asCents(amount1) + asCents(amount2);
    int absAllCents = abs(centsSum);
    int finalDollars = absAllCents / 100;
    int finalCents = absAllCents % 100;
    if (centsSum < 0) {
        finalDollars = -finalDollars;
        finalCents = -finalCents;
    }
    return Money(finalDollars, finalCents);
}

const Money operator -(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    int centsDifference = asCents(amount1) - asCents(amount2);
    int absAllCents = abs(centsDifference);
    int finalDollars = absAllCents / 100;
    int finalCents = absAllCents % 100;
    if (centsDifference < 0) {
        finalDollars = -finalDollars;
        finalCents = -finalCents;
    }
    return Money(finalDollars, finalCents);
}

bool operator ==(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    return ((amount1.getDollars() == amount2.getDollars())
        && (amount1.getCents() == amount2.getCents()));
}

bool operator <(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    return ((amount1.getDollars() < amount2.getDollars())
        && (amount1.getCents() < amount2.getCents()));
}

bool operator >(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    return ((amount1.getDollars() > amount2.getDollars())
        && (amount1.getCents() > amount2.getCents()));
}

const Money operator -(const Money& amount) {
    return Money(-amount.getDollars(), -amount.getCents());
}

Money Money::percent(const Money& amount, double percentage) const {
    int amountToCents = amount.getCents() + amount.getDollars() * 100;
    double pScaledMoney = amountToCents * percentage;
    int scaledDollars = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) / 100);
    int scaledCents = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) % 100);
    if (pScaledMoney < 0) {
        scaledDollars = -scaledDollars;
        scaledCents = -scaledCents;
    }
    return Money(scaledDollars, scaledCents);
}   

// Varying constructors
Money::Money() : dollars(0), cents(0) {}
Money::Money(int justDollars) : dollars(justDollars), cents(0) {}
Money::Money(double asMoney) : dollars(dollarsPart(asMoney)), cents(centsPart(asMoney)) {}
Money::Money(int withDollars, int withCents) {
    if ((withDollars < 0 && withCents > 0) || (withDollars > 0 && withCents < 0)) {
        cout << "You're fired";
        exit(1);
    }
    dollars = withDollars;
    cents = withCents;
}

void compareMoney(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {

    cout << "\nYour amount is " << amount1 << endl;
    cout << "My amount is " << amount2 << endl;

    if (amount1 == amount2)
        cout << "\nWe have the same amount of money\n" << endl;
    else
        cout << "\nSomeone has more money..\n" << endl;

    Money ourAmount = amount1 + amount2;
    cout << amount1 << " + " << amount2 <<
    " equals " << ourAmount << endl;
        Money amountDifference = amount1 - amount2;
    cout << amount1 << " - " << amount2 <<
        " equals " << amountDifference << endl;

    Money halfYourMoney = amount1.percent(amount1, 50);
    Money halfMyMoney = amount2.percent(amount2, 50);

    cout << "%50 of your money is " << halfYourMoney << endl;
    cout << "%50 of my money is " << halfMyMoney << endl;

    if (amount1 < amount2)
        cout << "\nI have more money!" << endl;
    if (amount1 > amount2)
        cout << "\nYou have more money!" << endl;
}   

int main() {

    cout << "Use a dollar sign ($) to enter a money value." << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    bool isRunning(true);
    while (isRunning) {

        try {

            Money yourAmount, myAmount(10, 9);
            cout << "Enter an amount of money: ";
            cin >> yourAmount;
            compareMoney(yourAmount, myAmount);

        } // Close try
        // Generalized Catch
        catch (std::exception & e) {
            cerr << "\nERROR : " << e.what() << '\n';
        }

        char choice('c');
        bool invalidChoice(true);
        // Option to run again
        while (cout << "\nRun Again? (y/n) \n\n" && (!(cin >> choice)) || (!(choice == 'n')) && (!(choice == 'y'))) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cerr << "\nERROR: The only valid answers are y/n. \n" << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 'y') {
            invalidChoice = false;
            cout << "\nSelected: \"" << choice << "\" ---> *** isRunning AGAIN. ***\n" << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 'n') {
            invalidChoice = false;
            isRunning = false;
            cout << "\nSelected: \"" << choice << "\" ---> *** EXITING. ***\n" << endl;
        }

        } // Close running
        do {
    cin.ignore();
        cout << '\n' << "Press enter to continue...";
    } while (cin.get() != '\n');

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is way too complicated. You could have just the `cents` as a member and have some helper functions that converts it to the respective parts. This will simplify most of your functions a lot.

```
const Money operator +(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) 
{
    return Money(amount1.cents + amount2.cents);
}

const Money operator -(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2)
{  
    return Money(amount1.cents - amount2.cents)
}

int dolarsFloor() const
{
    return cents / 100;
}

int centsReminder() const
{

    return cents % 100 ;
}
```

There are other things that can be improved but I just wanted to leave my 2 cents ;).

Comment: That's basically the most important point that needs to be made.

Answer (score 6):

None of your overloaded operators (except for the stream ones) need to be `friend`s. `operator+`, etc. can be defined inline and `operator==`, etc. can be defined non-member. The fact that you use the public interface in `operator==` is a strong hint that it doesn't need to be a `friend`.

There's a LOT of code duplication going on. The operators can be overloaded in terms of each other. (You should also make the relational operators `const`.)

```
bool operator >(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) const {
    return !(amount1 < amount2);
}
```

You forgot to implement `operator!=`:

```
bool operator !=(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) const {
    return !(amount1 == amount2);
}
```

---

If you have C++11, the [`std::put_money`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) and `std::get_money` functions from `<iomanip>` are available. First, choose your locale:

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
```

This will simplify your code:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& amount) {
    outputStream.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    outputSteam << std::put_money(dollars + cents);
    return outputStream;
}
```

`dollars + cents` isn't real code. However, I leave that as an exercise to you. Of course, it would potentially simplify things if you kept track of the entire amount as a double.

Comment: “*You should also make the relational operators `const`*” – that is solid advice for most member functions, but then you show a `bool operator>(const Money&, const Money&) const` that looks suspiciously like a free function rather than a member. Does the `const` qualifier even work there? What would be made `const`, considering that both arguments already are `const Money&`? There is no `this` pointer. But if it were a member function, how coukd the `operator>` take two arguments? Sorry, I'm still new to operator overloading in C++.

Comment: I diasagree with your friend comment. This is the one classic case where they are better as friends as this is one of those times were auto conversion is useful and only happens properly for friends. i want `Money + integer` to behave in the same way as `Integer + Money` this is what friend functions will achieve that members will not.

Comment: Also you can define friends inline. I do that all the time for simple functions.

Comment: You should never track money as a double. Floating point values can not store all values exactly and thus when you do other operations you get rounding errors.

Comment: +1 for using local to correctly format money. Though its probably better (for some definition of better) to use: `outputStream.imbue(std::locale());` as this will pick up the locale that the machine is running in and do the correct operation for that locale (thus its not just dollars and sense.

Comment: `!(a<b)` is `a>=b`, not `a>b`.

Comment: yes i think this is what you meant  `return amount2 < amount1;`

Answer (score 2):

- Although it's mostly personal preference, you could still add `std::` wherever needed and leave out all the `using`s.  This could reduce a bit of clutter towards the top.  Plus, you never included a `using` for `abs`, though the compiler may sometimes fail to catch that.
- Since you're using just dollars and cents, perhaps this class could be renamed to something more specific like `USD`.  Regardless, your print statements can still include the `$` character so that the user will know it's still a monetary value and not just a regular numerical value.
- There is a slight indentation inconsistency in the `centsPart()` statement:

  > ```
  >     int Money::centsPart(double amount) const {
  >     double doubleCents = amount * 100;
  >     int intCents = (round(fabs(doubleCents))) % 100;
  >     if (amount < 0)
  >         intCents = -intCents;
  >     return intCents;
  > }
  > ```
- This may not be a good way of handling error in a constructor:

  > ```
  > Money::Money(int withDollars, int withCents) {
  >     if ((withDollars < 0 && withCents > 0) || (withDollars > 0 && withCents < 0)) {
  >         cout << "You're fired";
  >         exit(1);
  >     }
  >     dollars = withDollars;
  >     cents = withCents;
  > }
  > ```

  The print statement, especially such an informal one, isn't necessary.  Just leave it for client code if desired.  The user may also not be expecting the program to exit after a failed construction, and I don't think it's too common.  It may be better to instead throw an exception on failure while making the user aware of that.

  You already have a `try` block in `main()` for two constructors and a member function, but it won't be of any use unless they can throw something.  If you do make this change, you can also catch that specific exception instead of just a generic `std::exception` and its associated error.  That could also make it easier to determine which entity has thrown an exception, if made possible for more than one of them (but not likely the default constructor).
- There's no need to mix up both `"\n"` and `endl`:

  > ```
  > if (amount1 == amount2)
  >     cout << "\nWe have the same amount of money\n" << endl;
  > else
  >     cout << "\nSomeone has more money..\n" << endl;
  > ```

  There's no need to also flush the buffer with `endl`, so just use any additional `"\n"`:

  ```
  if (amount1 == amount2)
      cout << "\nWe have the same amount of money\n\n";
  else
      cout << "\nSomeone has more money..\n\n";
  ```
- There's no need to have your own `return 0` at the end of `main()` in C++. The compiler will automatically add this same return.